# how to get json object in laravel controller

Tags: json, laravel, api

I'm performing and API that receive json object, but cannot read it. Actually I don't know if it should be received as Request, or how...

First I try to get the json and decode it to an array. After that, I return the same array to json in the response. But it's returned as empty ({})

That's my route

```
Route::post('enviar_encuestas', 'EncuestaUsuarioController@store');
```

And in my controller, for that method I perform the following

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $users = json_decode($request);
    return response()->json($users);
}
```

In Postman I send perform the following
HTTP POST Request to

```
https://encuestasapi.informixsys.com.ar/public/enviar_encuestas
```

I select Body and raw, after that I select JSON(application/json)
and write the following

```
{
        "id_encuesta" : 1,
        "email" : "asd@hotmail.com",
        "razon_social" : "asd",
        "nro_ref_autopack" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could retrieve the posted json data and return it back as json through:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $users = json_decode($request->json()->all());
    return response()->json($users);
}
```

Comment: `$request->all()` returns an associative array, no need to do json_decode given that you the `$request` is an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request`.

To return you can just do `return response()->json($request->all());`

Comment: Also, to decode JSON to an array, use the true flag `json_decode($json, true);` to return an associative array