# Postman failing to send json to PHP api

Tags: php, laravel, api, postman

```
    public function register(Request $request) {
//        $user = User::create([
//            'name' => $request->input('name'),
//            'email' => $request->input('email'),
//            'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password'))
//        ]);
//
//        return $user;

        return "test";
    }
```

Hi all,
basically, I'm trying to build a restful API with Laravel and my API is being hit by Postman, but when I send a JSON body my `$request` is an empty array.

It's the first time I'm touching Laravel so it's probably something obvious so thank you in advance !

Comment: Can you please add screenshot of postman request which you are sending? In general, You can use like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56363161/how-to-get-json-object-in-laravel-controller

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
use Exception;

  public function register(Request $request) {
       

 try {
          $user = User::create([
          'name' => $request->input('name'),
          'email' => $request->input('email'),
          'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password'))
        ]);
    
       return response()->json(['status' => true, 'message' => 'You have been register successfully', 'data' => $user]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['status' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage(), 'data' => []]);
        }
        
    }
```